# Facial Feature Detection in IOS using OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to do facial feature detection in iOS. I already am able to detect a face using OpenCV, but now want to detect all the 'features' in this face, so that I can perform recognition on them at a later time.

I found a library called flandmark, but it doesn't like it has a framework that I can use on iOS.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this?

Thanks
Nikhil Mehta

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to keep it as simple as possible and in this situation just use native iOS possibilities to do it if it is enough.

The main class is **`CIDetector`** of the `CoreImage` framework.
Below are the main methods

```
// create CIDetector object with CIDetectorTypeFace type
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                                  context:nil
                                                  options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];

// give it CIImage and receive an array with CIFaceFeature objects
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:newImage];
```

According to *Apple* docs **`CIFaceFeature`** contains next properties

```
@interface CIFaceFeature : CIFeature

 @property (readonly, assign) CGRect bounds;
 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL hasLeftEyePosition;
 @property (readonly, assign) CGPoint leftEyePosition;
 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL hasRightEyePosition;
 @property (readonly, assign) CGPoint rightEyePosition;
 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL hasMouthPosition;
 @property (readonly, assign) CGPoint mouthPosition;

 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL hasTrackingID;
 @property (readonly, assign) int trackingID;
 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL hasTrackingFrameCount;
 @property (readonly, assign) int trackingFrameCount;

 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL hasFaceAngle;
 @property (readonly, assign) float faceAngle;

 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL hasSmile;
 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL leftEyeClosed;
 @property (readonly, assign) BOOL rightEyeClosed;

 @end
```

Also there is a great [Raywenderlich article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1) about GCD, that implements face features detection and here is its [Final project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/GooglyPuff_End_1.zip). It finds people's eyes' position and overlays it with some funny eyes.

And finally part of the code from the project and the screenshot from it.

```
- (UIImage *)faceOverlayImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                              context:nil
                                              options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
    // Get features from the image
    CIImage* newImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:newImage];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    //Draws this in the upper left coordinate system
    [image drawInRect:imageRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (CIFaceFeature *faceFeature in features) {
        CGRect faceRect = [faceFeature bounds];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        // CI and CG work in different coordinate systems, we should translate to
        // the correct one so we don't get mixed up when calculating the face position.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, imageRect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        if ([faceFeature hasLeftEyePosition]) {
            CGPoint leftEyePosition = [faceFeature leftEyePosition];
            CGFloat eyeWidth = faceRect.size.width / kFaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor;
            CGFloat eyeHeight = faceRect.size.height / kFaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor;
            CGRect eyeRect = CGRectMake(leftEyePosition.x - eyeWidth/2.0f,
                                        leftEyePosition.y - eyeHeight/2.0f,
                                        eyeWidth,
                                        eyeHeight);
            [self drawEyeBallForFrame:eyeRect];
        }

        if ([faceFeature hasRightEyePosition]) {
            CGPoint leftEyePosition = [faceFeature rightEyePosition];
            CGFloat eyeWidth = faceRect.size.width / kFaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor;
            CGFloat eyeHeight = faceRect.size.height / kFaceBoundsToEyeScaleFactor;
            CGRect eyeRect = CGRectMake(leftEyePosition.x - eyeWidth / 2.0f,
                                        leftEyePosition.y - eyeHeight / 2.0f,
                                        eyeWidth,
                                        eyeHeight);
            [self drawEyeBallForFrame:eyeRect];
        }

        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }

    UIImage *overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return overlayImage;
}

- (void)drawEyeBallForFrame:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGFloat x, y, eyeSizeWidth, eyeSizeHeight;
    eyeSizeWidth = rect.size.width * kRetinaToEyeScaleFactor;
    eyeSizeHeight = rect.size.height * kRetinaToEyeScaleFactor;

    x = arc4random_uniform((rect.size.width - eyeSizeWidth));
    y = arc4random_uniform((rect.size.height - eyeSizeHeight));
    x += rect.origin.x;
    y += rect.origin.y;

    CGFloat eyeSize = MIN(eyeSizeWidth, eyeSizeHeight);
    CGRect eyeBallRect = CGRectMake(x, y, eyeSize, eyeSize);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, eyeBallRect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

[image: Screenshot from the Raywenderlich's project]

Hope it'll help